# What changes need to be made to my code to create a new 3D perspective view in Revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I copied some code from [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/06/revit-camera-settings-project-plasma-da4r-and-ai.html#2) to create a 3D perspective view in an already open Revit file. However when I run the Execute method absolutely nothing happens. There's no exceptions thrown or errors in the output log, so I think it is simply an issue with my copy of the code.

What do I need to do to make this code create a 3D perspective view and/or open it in Revit?

```
using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "CameraTransaction"))
            {
                t.Start();
                IEnumerable<ViewFamilyType> viewFamilyTypes = from elem in new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
                                                              let type = elem as ViewFamilyType
                                                              where type.ViewFamily == ViewFamily.ThreeDimensional
                                                              select type;
                
                View3D issue3DCameraView = View3D.CreatePerspective(doc, viewFamilyTypes.First().Id);
                issue3DCameraView.Name = "Issue_" + issue.Name;

                PerspectiveCamera cam = issue.Viewpoints[i].PerspectiveCamera;
                XYZ position = new XYZ(cam.CameraViewPoint.X, cam.CameraViewPoint.Y, cam.CameraViewPoint.Z);
                XYZ up = new XYZ(cam.CameraUpVector.X, cam.CameraUpVector.Y, cam.CameraUpVector.Z);
                XYZ sightDir = new XYZ(cam.CameraDirection.X, cam.CameraDirection.Y, cam.CameraDirection.Z);

                var orientation = new ViewOrientation3D(position, up, sightDir);
                issue3DCameraView.SetOrientation(orientation);

                Parameter farClip = issue3DCameraView.LookupParameter("Far Clip Active");
                farClip.Set(0);

                Parameter cropRegionVisible = issue3DCameraView.LookupParameter("Crop Region Visible");
                cropRegionVisible.Set(1);

                Parameter cropView = issue3DCameraView.LookupParameter("Crop View");
                cropView.Set(1);
/* Removed                
//Added in an attempt to make the code work
                RevitCommandId commandId = RevitCommandId.LookupPostableCommandId(PostableCommand.Default3DView);
                if (app.CanPostCommand(commandId))
                {
                    app.PostCommand(commandId);
                }*/

                t.Commit();
            }
```

Edit: Further study of this issue shows that the transaction just sort of stops at the "issue3DCameraView.SetOrientation(orientation);" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this code lay in the source for issue.Viewpoints[i].PerspectiveCamera. The code itself works fine.

I am leaving this answer here for the benefit of those who are to come after me.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from looking at your code what might be wrong... except, of course, the `PostCommand` call that you added. That will definitely not help, on the contrary.

Rather than trying to fix your code for you, I suggest you study some of the other articles listed in The Building coder topic group on [Creating and Setting Up a 3D View](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.37) first.